# Can I have a single instance of Interface

Tags: java, android, architecture, singleton

In my Android application I have a class which gives me static string values; something like this:

```
public class VehicleInfo {

    public static String getVehicleEnginePower(boolean isNew) {
        return isNew ? "1800CC" : "1600CC";
    }
}
```

Now I have another category, so I will have to pass another Boolean, and I will get the value I need. However, these categories will keep on increasing. So I looked into the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) which looks promising for quick enhancement. To ensure this I will make the `VehicleInfo` class as an Interface and then I will have other classes implement `VehicleInfo`.

```
public interface VehicleInfo {
    String getVehicleEnginePower();
}

public class NewVehicle implements VehicleInfo {
    @Override
    public String getVehicleEnginePower() {
        return "1800CC";
    }
}
```

and the other category classes will also be something like this. In this way I will have to add another class for all the new categories.

The question I wanted to ask is: is there a way that I can have single instance of this interface? Because in the whole application flow, a user will only be able to see one category until he switches to another category.

I don't want to instantiate these classes at multiple points. To clarify my question, I want to do something like this at the start of my application:

```
if (isNew) {
    VehicleInfo vehicleInfor = new NewVehicle();
}
```

And in the whole application, whenever I call `VehicleInfo.getVehicleEnginePower`, it should always return engine power from the NewVehicle class.

Is something like this possible? Or am I just being silly and I will have to instantiate this interface on multiple points?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a singleton?

Comment: why don't you try `enum`

Comment: As per your requirement you can use Builder Pattern .

Here is nice explanation with example for the same [link](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder)

Comment: @shamosel yeah something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need a singleton here

```
public class VehicleInfoManager {
    private static VehicleInfoManager INSTANCE = new VehicleInfoManager();

    private VehicleInfo currentVehicleInfo;

    public static VehicleInfoManager getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setCurrentVehicleInfo(VehicleInfo info) {
        this.currentVehicleInfo = info;
    }

    public String getVehicleEnginePower() {
        return this.currentVehicleInfo.getVehicleEnginePower();
    }

    private VehicleInfoManager() {
        // Constructor private by default
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from everywhere like this

```
VehicleInfoManager.getInstance().getVehicleEnginePower()

//Or set current info like this
VehicleInfoManager.getInstance().setCurrentVehicleInfo(new NewVehicle())
```

Just be careful as currentVehicleInfo is null by default so you need to handle null pointer cases.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly.

My solution to this would be `Enum`

```
public enum VehicleEnginePower {
    NEW ("1800CC"),
    OLD ("1600CC"),

    private final String name;       

    private Modes(String s) {
        name = s;
    } 

    public String toString() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Then you can do**

```
if (isNew) {
   String powerOfEngine = VehicleEnginePower.NEW.toString();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use Enum as I don't have multiple string values, I have many specs like, EnginePower, Color, NumberOfSeats and so on.
And as per this link, https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html
You should strictly avoid using enums on Android.